# How to route PEX/PERT tubing for cast iron radiator system in ceiling

Tags: heat

I'm in the process of building a basement apartment. Our home's hot water radiant heating system consists of a gas-powered boiler and cast iron radiators. It's a closed system with 18 radiators.

The old iron pipe running below the basement ceiling was wrapped in asbestos and removed, leaving the need for new pipes. I plan to replace them with plastic tubing this time and place them inside the joists for max ceiling height. Instead of the 2-pipe system before, I'm running 1/2" home runs to each radiator. I'm also dividing the 3 levels of the home into 3 zones so they can be controlled independently with 3 separate thermostats. Each zone will have its own manifold and zone valve.

You can see a schematic I've drawn below (click to make it big enough to read!).

My tubing is [1/2" PERT](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Oil-Creek-HF9051000-1-2-HeatFlex-PE-2708-PERT-Tubing-1000-ft-Coil) (Recyclable and flexible!).

Before I start drilling holes in everything, I have some questions:

- The PERT product above says it has a 5" bend radius. I modeled on 6" just in case. Do any of these turns seem impossible?
- Is there any disadvantage to using elbows as opposed to a bend in places where I can't make the turn?
- How should I insulate the send/hot lines while they are in a rail like the one pictured below?
- When it comes to how I'll run the tubing along each joist in rails, I've shown two options below. Which is better? Would love to understand the advantages to either. Option B seems ideal for space overall.
- Any other tips or warnings?

[image: Radiator Routing Sketch]

[image: Options for Joist Fastening]

[image: Rail on 1" center]

Comment: Half inch tubing? Are you sure about this? You've done the flow calculations and you don't need to use 3/4 inch?

Comment: This is waaaay too many questions in one. While they're all related to your project, insulation is a separate question from bend radius is separate from elbows. Also, asking which is "better" is opinion based and that makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a P=1500W radiator, how much water flow does that need? Thermal capacity of water is Ct=4180J/°C.kg, DeltaT is the temperature difference between the inlet and outlet of the radiator. Assuming 1 liter is 1kg of water,

Water flow (l/s) = P/(DeltaT*Cth)

For P=1500W DeltaT=20°C flow=0.018 l/s ; in a 12mm ID pipe that's 20mmH2O pressure drop per meter of pipe ; you have to count both hot and cold pipes so let's go with 20m, that's a 400mmH2O pressure drop or 0.04 bar. Absolutely fine.

Now suppose the greens vote a law to force you to replace your gas heater with a heat pump, like they did in EU, Germany, France, etc. No more burning evil fossil fuels! You now have a deltaT of 5°C, and a much lower "hot" water temperature. So you probably have to fit bigger radiators, but do you have to also change all the pipes?

P=1500W DeltaT=20°C ; flow=0.071 l/s. Note pressure drop increases as the square of flow rate so using a 4x lower deltaT which means a 4x higher flow implies a 16x higher pressure drop. So now you get 6.4mH2O pressure drop, give or take, which begins to get quite annoying.

Personally I would up the diameter one notch, to 16/20mm instead of your 13/16mm, as a future-proofing measure against political stupidity.

You should redo the flow and pressure drop calculations carefully.

I would also definitely not make that many holes in the joists, instead drop the basement ceiling by the diameter of one pipe (plus conduit) and take that opportunity to make a soundproof suspended drywall ceiling. All you have to do is hang it using soundproofing fixtures instead of the normal ones, so it's not difficult. Also fill the space between joists with fiberglass or rockwool to dampen sound.

Now if you use naked tube and need to bend it, you can use these handy guides:

[image]

No idea what the Americans call it, but basically you clip the pipe in it and you have an elbow at the minimum allowed bending radius without risk of pinching the pipe. It stays on the pipe, so you have to buy a lot of these, but they cost 1.50€.

> How should I insulate the send/hot lines while they are in a rail like the one pictured below?

You could blow some insulation between the joists once it's done, for example expanded graphite beads. Going with my drop ceiling solution I'd just use these:

[image]

It's PEX pipe in a conduit. If you put it in a concrete slab the conduit allows to pull out the PEX if it ever fails. In a situation like yours it will protect the PEX from nails, screws, drill bits, and perhaps rodents. It's supposed to be installed quite loose and not neatly/tightly tied because it needs to be able to move out of the way when someone drills.

Answer (score 0):

Option B.  You don't want to be drilling in between your pipe runs.  1.5" is plenty of distance from the top of the joist.  Potentially having to weave your pipe in between other pipes while running the pipe is also a nightmare.

Are you using alpha clips when you run your pipe through joists?

Your hole in the joist have to be very dead on, are you making a jig to keep them in the exact same place?

Fittings are typically where you get leaks.  The more fittings the more potential for leaks in the future.  Pex fittings also typically (can go expansion pex) go inside the pipe and reduce the flow.  Less fittings means better flow.

Isn't the rail just plastic?  What is the difficulty in insulating?  Are you just worried about the 1/8" portion of the pipe that is touching the rail clip?  What temp are you sending your water through?  or does the rail keep the pipe close too close to the joist?  If too close to joist just make standoffs for the rails.

You'll adjust your flow at the manifold based on the overall length of each run so ensure similar flow in the case where all zones are open on the manifold?